# How to turn adversary against encryption of zeroes into adversary against random bits?

Tags: encryption, provable-security

I recently read the article [Nonce-Based Symmetric Encryption](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/nonce.pdf) by Rogaway, where he presents two different notions of indistinguishability, which he calls **ind$** and **ind**, respectively. Here's the definitions of these to notions:

First, let $A^g$ be an algorithm with access to an oracle $g$, and let $\Pi = (\mathcal{E},\mathcal{D})$ be an encryption scheme with key space $\mathrm{Key}$.

Ind\$ is then defined as follows:
$$ \mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind$}} = \mathrm{Pr}[K \xleftarrow{$} \mathrm{Key} : A ^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot)} \Rightarrow 1] - \mathrm{Pr}[A ^{\mathcal{$}(\cdot)} \Rightarrow 1],$$

where $ \$(\cdot)$ is a random oracle, returning random bits equal to the block size of $\mathcal{E}$. In other words: ind$ asks an adversary to distinguish between messages encrypted by the real encryption scheme and random bits.

Ind is defined as:
$$ \mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind}} = \mathrm{Pr}[K \xleftarrow{$} \mathrm{Key} : A ^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot)} \Rightarrow 1] - \mathrm{Pr}[K \xleftarrow{$} \mathrm{Key} : A ^{\mathcal{E}_K(0^{|\cdot|})} \Rightarrow 1].$$

That is, ind asks an adversary, when quarrying the input message $M$ to the oracles, to distinguish between the real encryption of $M$, and the encryption of $0^{|M|}$.

He then claims that

> "It is easy to verify that the ind$-notion of security implies the ind-notion, and by a tight reduction".

**My question:**

Intuitively, the implication seems easy enough:
If $\Pi$ is ind\$-secure, then encryption of $0^{|M|}$ will be indistinguishable from random, so we just get the "ind\$-game". However, how would you go about showing the tightness of the reduction? Usually I'm used to doing this by a reduction like so: assume you have an ind-adversary that breaks the ind-security, how can you turn this into an (effective) adversary against the ind\$-security of $\Pi$? But I don't really see how an adversary against ind can be turned into an (effective) adversary against ind\$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite simple.
Given your adversary $A$ against ind you construct an adversary $A'$ against ind$ by simply forwarding the queries and answers. (This may seem stupid but please bear with me.)

Consider now, the difference between the advantage of $A$ and $A'$:
$$\mathrm{Pr}[K \xleftarrow{$} \mathrm{Key} : A ^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot)} \Rightarrow 1] - \mathrm{Pr}[A ^{\mathcal{$}(\cdot)} \Rightarrow 1]-(\mathrm{Pr}[K \xleftarrow{$} \mathrm{Key} : A ^{\mathcal{E}_K(\cdot)} \Rightarrow 1] - \mathrm{Pr}[K \xleftarrow{$} \mathrm{Key} : A ^{\mathcal{E}_K(0^{|\cdot|})} \Rightarrow 1])$$
$$= \mathrm{Pr}[K \xleftarrow{$} \mathrm{Key} : A ^{\mathcal{E}_K(0^{|\cdot|})} \Rightarrow 1] - \mathrm{Pr}[A ^{\mathcal{$}(\cdot)} \Rightarrow 1]$$

If this distance were non-negligible, we could build a successful adversary $A''$ against ind$\mathrm{$}$ as follows: Whenever $A$ queries a message, $A''$ queries $0^{|\cdot|}$ instead and returns the answer to $A$.

It's easy to see that the advantage of $A''$ is excactly the difference from above. Therefore you get $$\mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind$}} = \mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind}}  - \mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind$}}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\cdot\mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind$}} = \mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind}}$$
$$\Rightarrow\mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind$}} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\mathbf{Adv}_{\Pi}^{\mathrm{ind}}$$